# Fire command from custom canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

I develop application with MVVM pattern. In my viewmodel project I have custom Command. In View I have custom canvas. **I want to fire command from my canvas code behind** but I dont have idea how.

My app startup (startup is in other project):

```
private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   // init main ViewModel
   var viewModel = new MainViewModel(Container);
   // init and show window
   var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
   mainWindow.Show();
   mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

I dont want to have reference to ViewModel in View, because I need reference to View in ViewModel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you usually do this is implement your own COMMAND in the CustomCanvas class. After that, you bind that command against command handler in viewmodel.

Just like you do with button:

```
<Button
  Command="{Binding YourVmCommand}"
/>
```

Makes sense?

To implement such functionality, you need to hack through ButtonBase.cs and see how it's done.
There's a lot code involved, but the idea is very simple.

1) Create new property in your View.

```
public ICommand Command { get; set; }
```

2) Bind to it in XAML

3) Execute it in View, when you need.

```
if(Command != null && Command.CanExecute(parameter))
  Command.Execute(parameter);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I dont need xaml. I want to fire command after drop event in canvas directly to viewmodel. Is that possible? Maybe I know bad to your solution...

Comment: Yes you can do that, it's just not gonna reusable. If you don't care about it, then all you do is just use (YourCanvas.DataContext as MainViewModel).YourCommand(); If you wan't to die then you can use ((dynamic)(YourCanvas.DataContext)).YourCommand() :P

Comment: Or Alternatively (YourCanvas.DataContext as MainViewModel).YourCommand.Execute()

Comment: I see, I know that but in this solution I have to reference to Viewmodel from View... Maybe my ideas are absolutely bad. Because I want reference View in Viewmodel and in Viewmodel I want to keep List of component on my canvas. And every component has reference instance of item from other Viewmodel collection. This is my first MVVM app and I dont have idea how to do correctly.

Comment: Yes I hear what you say, but if you want to follow MVVM then ViewModel can't know anything about View. Restructure your application.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your advices. I think I dont need to restructure my app. I have only to know how to communicate between view and viewmodel - I mean this is my biggest problem. But thank you :)